# to make the log in link align with other links

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do I get the login button link to lie in the same line as other links?
I've tried adjusting margin and padding for the anchor tags but it's not working.

HTML code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="#myModal">
  <img border="0" src="/images/login.jpg">
</a>
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `img` css:

```
a[data-toggle="modal"] > img {margin: 13px 0;}
```